# a measure of difference for arrangements of sphere points

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, pr.probability, it.information-theory

Suppose one has a distribution of $N$ points on the sphere. Is there an agreed upon metric for the difference of this distribution and $N$ equidistant points on the sphere? To me *entropy* seems like the right concept, but I'm not sure how to go about defining it.

Answer (score 3):

there exists a great variety of metrics for the uniformity of points on a (hyper)sphere; the reference list of this [2010 paper](http://www.lana.lt/journal/36/Bakshaev.pdf) will point you to them. For a comparison of the different metrics:

- A. Figueiredo, *Comparison of tests of uniformity defined on the hypersphere*, Statistics and Probability Letters, **77**, 329 (2007).
- P.J. Diggle, N.I. Fisher, and A.J. Lee, *A comparison of tests of uniformity for spherical data*, Australian Journal of Statistics, **27**, 53 (1985).

Comment: In other words, there is no unique concept of "N equidistant points on the sphere," except for a few very symmetric cases where the metrics agree.